# I want to access my state object after the setState Initializes which state system should i use

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## My Color Game

I want to get the value of set state but componentDidMount just gives me the previous value of state without updating it

Can anyone tell me which state system to use to resolve this problem Thanxs

```
    state = {
      
        color: '',
        main_color: '',


    }

    componentDidMount() {
    

        let box_count = 3;

        let byee = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes");

        let main_color = this.state.main_color;
        for (let i = 0; i < box_count; i++) {
            byee[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

                if (byee[i].style.backgroundColor === main_color) {

                    win();

                } else {

                    loose();
                     
                    console.log(byee[i].style.backgroundColor);
                    console.log(main_color);
                }
            })
        }
        function win() {
            console.log("winner");
        }
        function loose() {
            console.log("loose");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are calling it inside the `componentDidMount()`, please read [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Comment: There is a typo, I believe.you have written state with a uppercase S "this.State.main_color" change it to "this.state.main_color"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
let main_color = this.State.main_color;
```

To:

```
let main_color = this.state.main_color;
```

**Notice to `State` which should use as `state` without capital letter.**